# PHP code to find time of a city inputted through a input box

Tags: php, search, time

I have this code,

```
 <?php  
// XML File  
$feed_url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=dubai&format=xml&extra=localObsTime&num_of_days=5&key=42esgfa4pfqp6zwgr4egjbph";  

// INITIATE CURL. 
$curl = curl_init(); 

// CURL SETTINGS. 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"$feed_url"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 

// GRAB THE XML FILE. 
$xxml = curl_exec($curl); 

curl_close($curl); 

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xxml); 

$flag=0;
// Loop through ... only pick the first one
foreach ($xml->current_condition as $item) {
if($flag==0){
echo" 
Dubai Time And Date: {$item->localObsDateTime}
<br />
";

}
$flag=1;
}

?>
```

The above code will give me local time and date of the city of Dubai.

I need to take the city value from a text input box and replace "dubai" with that.

This will do the text box part.

I tried to incorporate, but getting some weird time.

Comment: And what have you tried so far to achieve your goal?

Comment: Use php forms to enter the city and replace every occurrence of dubai in your code by $_POST['city'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isSet($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'])
{
    // XML File  
    $feed_url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=" . urlencode(trim($_POST['city'])) . "&format=xml&extra=localObsTime&num_of_days=5&key=xxxxxxxxx";  

    // INITIATE CURL. 
    $curl = curl_init(); 

    // CURL SETTINGS. 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"$feed_url"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 

    // GRAB THE XML FILE. 
    $xxml = curl_exec($curl); 

    curl_close($curl); 

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xxml); 

    $flag=0;
    // Loop through ... only pick the first one
    foreach ($xml->current_condition as $item) {
    if($flag==0){
    echo 
    ucfirst($_POST['city']) . " Time And Date: {$item->localObsDateTime}
    <br />
    ";

    }
    $flag=1;
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo (isSet($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] ? $_POST['city'] : ''); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search City">
</form>
```

Comment: echo ucfirst($_POST['city'])." Time And Date: {$item->localObsDateTime}

Comment: thanks "userNOID" that code is working, thanks. Little more help. Can you put a text box near the input box like "search city"

Comment: Text box? Do you mean textarea? Please explain. :)

Comment: your code give me just an input box, right? I need a box with "search city" near it.

Comment: Did you mean this? (see my updated answer)

Comment: that is working perfectly, but when I searched "new york" I got this error, Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home4/xxxth/public_html/xxxxx.com/ip-lookup/time/time.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /home4/xxxth/public_html/xxxxx.com/ip-lookup/time/time.php(20): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /home4/xxxth/public_html/xxxx.com/ip-lookup/time/time.php on line 20

Comment: That is because of trim function it turns new york to newyork instead of new%20york in the url, just remove trim :)

Comment: Trim just removes spaces at the start and at the end of string.

Comment: no my friend, it's not helping

Comment: Try this: urlencode(trim($_POST['city']))
(see my updated answer)